# Mysql checksum for master-slave replication returning different values, despite being identical

Tags: mysql, replication

I've set up a master slave replication in mysql and to make sure that I know if the data starts getting  out of sync I created a script that:

1. Locks both databases on both servers.
2. Prints the checksums of all the tables to a text file.
3. Copy's the slave checksum text file to master.
4. Compares the both files to see if anything is different.

But on some tables I got different checksums. So I downloaded both those tables and created another script to find whats different on them. And Nothing is different! They're identical.

I do have slightly different versions of mysql installed, could this be causing it?

```
+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                       |
+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.5.34                      |
| protocol_version        | 10                          |
| slave_type_conversions  |                             |
| version                 | 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.13.04.1-log |
| version_comment         | (Ubuntu)                    |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                      |
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnu            |
+-------------------------+-----------------------------+

+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                       |
+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.5.37                      |
| protocol_version        | 10                          |
| slave_type_conversions  |                             |
| version                 | 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log |
| version_comment         | (Ubuntu)                    |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                      |
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnu            |
+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Anyone of you know what could be causing this?

Comment: Is the default row_format in those DBs different? MySQL doc says: *If the checksums for two tables are different, then it is almost certain that the tables are different in some way.*

Comment: What is the default row_format and where do I find it? I compared "show variables" on the two servers and they are identical except for "timestamp" differing 1404637139 / 1404637195

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628885/what-row-format-is-my-table

Comment: Ok got it. They're all compact. I did "show table status" and I don't know if this is relevant. But they show different numbers of rows in the tables, but when I do a count they are the same.